# Ionic 4/ Angular 6 button class does not stay 'activated'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a page with 2 buttons.  I want one to be 'activated' on launch (which works), and then, as the user clicks a button, it will be activated, and the other one will de-activate.  For some reason, although the behaviour on load is fine, once you start clicking the behaviour fails. What I am doing incorrectly?

Template

```
<div class="button-container">
  <ion-button [ngClass]="{'activated': view === 'meetings'}" class="meeting-button" meetings (click)="changeView('meetings')"><ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon> <span stretch>Meetings</span></ion-button>
  <ion-button [ngClass]="{'activated': view === 'tasks'}" class="task-button" tasks (click)="changeView('tasks')"><ion-icon name="list-box"></ion-icon><span stretch>Tasks</span></ion-button>
</div>
```

TS

```
this.view = 'meetings';

changeView(view) {
  this.view = view;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to debug it. Put your logic in a method to see what might be happening. 
[ngClass]="{'activated': newMethod()}". Return true or false based on this.view.

Comment: your code is woring fine when click on button then it add activated class. i think you have not set css for show `activated`